# How can I hide the mouse cursor?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wanna ask if someone can provide me a c++ code in which I can hide/show the pointer of the mouse when pressing a specific key..
I found several codes written for only TURBO C++, none of which can be compiled and run using dev c++ or even visual c++..

I tried running the codes I found in Dev C++ but I only get lots of errors and incompatibilities..

I also found several articles that says I can use the function ShowCursor but it just wouldn't work..

Comment: Only if you de-capitalize your title.

Comment: Instead of being a [copy and paste programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming), try to read and understand how the code sample you've found actually works, and you'll probably be able to get it working in your environment, and maybe even learn something in the process.

Comment: Also, the `pointers` tag doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: `ShowCursor` is known to work.

Comment: @user - You might even try `ShowCursor(false)`.

Answer (score 5):

In fact hiding the cursor can turn out to be quite a task, depending on what you want to achive. If you're programming a GUI-application using the WinAPI it is pretty easy.

Just calling ShowCursor(false); once might turn out not to work in some cases though, since the ShowCursor function only "sets an internal display counter". The cursor is displayed until this counter is smaller than 0 (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it). You could try something like this:

```
while(ShowCursor(false)>=0);
```

to ensure the counter gets below 0.
This will however only hide the cursor inside your applications window, if you're using newer Windows versions like Windows 7. Hiding the cursor all over the system could turn out to be a lot more difficult.

If you are programming a console application ShowCursor won't show any effect as far as I've tested it. Using the following code:

```
while(ShowCursor(false)>=0);    
std::cout<<ShowCursor(false)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<ShowCursor(true)<<std::endl;
```

we can see, that the counter definitely is below 0, but still the cursor is displayed. I haven't come up with a solution to this so far.

Comment: A workaround: You need the vertical resolution and then call `SetCursorPos(0,YRES);`. Can put that into a loop if necessary.

Comment: I am facing the same problem in Console window. I suspect this statement of MSDN: `When Windows starts up, it checks if you have a mouse. If so, then the cursor show count is initialized to zero; otherwise, it is initialized to negative one`. Because I kind of get two -1s (before it starts to decrement below -1) when I call it multiple times. I think in the latest windows it doesnt recognise the connected mouse or the trackpad as an installed mouse. please try similarly

Comment: @mınxomaτ Did you find the solution? I have described the things I tried here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110704/showcursorfalse-does-not-work please check

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the SetCursor function, setting the cursor to a NULL handle (e.g SetCursor(NULL)) will remove the cursor from the screen.